# Case issue when using the include operator in MVC, LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following query which works to a certain extent : -

```
var Query = from e in dataContext.Employees.Include(e => e.EmployeeEvents)
                           orderby e.EmpFirstname
                           select e;
```

The tables 'Employees' and 'EmployeeEvents' have a one to many relationship and the name of the key that joins them is called 'EmpID'
The problem is that not all of the records in 'EmployeeEvents' are being returned. This appears to be becuase some of the values in the 'EmployeeEvents.EmpID'
do not all have the same case. Only the records that match the case in Employees.EmpID are being returned.
Is there a way to tell the query to ingnore the case of the records?

Thanks

Comment: What is your database collation?

Comment: it is Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: OK, I thought it might be due to a case-sensitive collation - but that isn't the issue.

Comment: Wait, the query is executed in the database. If the columns are case insensitive (i.e. their collation doesn't override the db collation) case shouldn't matter. What happens if you do a join in SSMS?

Comment: If I extract the sql statement from the LINQ query and run it in SQL management console it runs perfectly okay. So the issue must somehow lie in the code?